# Prevent input to get cleared when the parend is modified

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Can I have some inputs on this ?

## Issue

When a form or a parent element of a form is modified, the text that was typed inside the inputs of the form get cleared. As this snipper show :

```js
function modifyParent() {
  document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML += "<br>a line get added";
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<form>
  <input type="text" id="child">
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="modifyParent()">click</button>
</div>
```

Hello everyone,

## Solution 1

I found a first esay way to prevent it if I know where the parent is modified. As this snipper show

```js
function modifyParent() {
  var child = document.getElementById("child");
  child.setAttribute("value", child.value)
  document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML += "<br>a line get added";
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<form>
  <input type="text" id="child" value="">
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="modifyParent()">click</button>
</div>
```

This solution look great, but only if i know where ans when the parent is modified. Also if i have a multiple inputs i need to loop on `document.getElementsByTagName("input")`.

## Solution 2

Since i dont know how many buttons i have and how many inputs, this is my best solution so far :

```js
function modifyParent() {
  setInputValues();
  document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML += "<br>a line get added";
}

function setInputValues() {
  for (var c of document.getElementsByTagName("input"))
    c.setAttribute("value", c.value);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<form>
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="modifyParent()">click</button>
</div>
```

It work well for multiple inputs but i have to call the `setInputValues()` function before i modify any parent everytime. I started to consider to add setInterval on this function but I stop here because i'm starting to go a bit far and it's very likely that their is a better way.

Any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner solution is to use a new element for the messages. This way you can set the messages inside a container without messing with the inputs.

```js
const messageBox = document.querySelector(".messages");
function modifyParent() {
  messageBox.innerHTML += "<br>a line get added";
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <form>
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
  </form>
  
  <button type="button" onclick="modifyParent()">click</button>
  
  <div class="messages"></div>
</div>
```

Another quick notice, `innerHTML` is vulnerable for [XSS attacks](https://gomakethings.com/preventing-cross-site-scripting-attacks-when-using-innerhtml-in-vanilla-javascript/) Try using `createElement` and `appendChild` if possible.

```js
const parent = document.getElementById("parent");
function modifyParent() {
  const br = document.createElement("br");
  const text = document.createTextNode("a line get added");
  
  parent.appendChild(br);
  parent.appendChild(text);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <form>
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
  </form>
  
  <button type="button" onclick="modifyParent()">click</button>
  
  <div class="messages"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just put text for the example to keep it simple but in fact i add other inputs (on the same level at the first one). So i really have to modify the direct parent.

Comment: @JulienMaret The second example should still work since it uses the `appendChild` method. I modified it to not use the messageBox anymore.